# How to combine two projects into one project?

Tags: xcode, subproject

I want to add an existing project in my existing developed project. I have tried drag those project in my developed project and set the header and other linker flag. I have access only forward declaration using this but I want access imprort "subprojectcontroller.h" but i didn't access those file. Can you please provide proper steps.

second project does not have static library.

Thanks
Kiran

Comment: Why you are done the one project in to two parts ?

Comment: I don't have one project in two parts.I have two separate projects already working independently fine. I want to add the second project into the first project completely.So that i can access the files of the second project in my first project.

Comment: Two different project into one Project strange.

Comment: My Project A,needs to implement a feature (video call) which is in project B. but i cant add the code/some files from project B directly and do his, because there are lots of dependencies in project B (project B already has two sub-projects in it.). That is why i wanted to add project B as a sub-project to my project A, so that i can access the files in B i need ,to make the video call in A.

Comment: Do a separate code for each project, Instead of drag and drop codes from another project.